# Array of fields to linked list in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to create a linked series of nodes based on the data within an array. I have the head node in which I want to attach the linked nodes, however, when using UNWIND or FOREACH I end up with the head node linking to each linking node individually instead of like a linked list.

$locations contains an array of objects which has the information needed to create the nodes I require. I cannot create the nodes before and do a collect since I have no unique way of fetching those specific types of nodes I just created as it should be based on what head node they are linking to.

```
CREATE (head:Game:Trail{
  GUID: apoc.create.uuid(),
  creationDate: datetime(),
  title: $title,
  description: $description
})
```

Option 1

```
FOREACH (trail IN $locations |
  CREATE (a:Pin:Trail{ GUID: apoc.create.uuid(), creationDate: datetime(), text: trail.hint.text, lat: trail.lat, lng: trail.lng })
  MERGE (head)-[:LEADS_TO]->(a)
  MERGE (a)<-[r1:IS_ABOUT]-(image:Image:Media{GUID: apoc.create.uuid(), filename: trail.blobFile.filename})
    ON CREATE SET a.imageURL = 'https://......../' + image.GUID + '.' + trail.blobFile.extension
  SET head = a
)
```

Option 2

```
UNWIND $locations as trail
CALL apoc.lock.nodes([head])
WITH head, trail

MATCH (head)-[:LEADS_TO*0..]->(end)
  WHERE NOT (end)-[:LEADS_TO]->()

CREATE (end)-[:LEADS_TO]->(a:Pin:Trail{ GUID: apoc.create.uuid(), creationDate: datetime(), text: trail.hint.text, lat: trail.lat, lng: trail.lng })
```

The output should be of this format

(head)-[LEADS_TO]->(node)-[LEADS_TO]->(node2)

However, both of the options I have tried produce the same output I end up with something of the format like:

(head)-[LEADS_TO]->(node), (head)-[LEADS_TO]->(node2)\

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having a bit of an APOC day here - there's probably a Cypher way to do it, but given some dummy data:

```
:param locations => [
    { hint: { text: 'first stop' }, lat: 1, long: 1 },
    { hint: { text: 'second stop' }, lat: 2, long: 1 },
    { hint: { text: 'last stop' }, lat: 3, long: 1 }
]
```

The following chunk of APOC-heavy Cypher will create the nodes, create a linked list from the nodes with `apoc.nodes.link` and then link the first node in the chain to the 'head' node:

```
CREATE (head:Game:Trail {
    GUID: apoc.create.uuid(),
    creationDate: datetime(),
    title: 'Some title',
    description: 'Some description'
})
WITH head, [trail in $locations | { GUID: apoc.create.uuid(), creationDate: datetime(), text: trail.hint.text, lat: trail.lat, long: trail.long }] as trails
CALL apoc.create.nodes(['Pin', 'Trail'], trails) YIELD node
WITH head, collect(node) as nodes
CALL apoc.nodes.link(nodes, 'LEADS_TO')
WITH head(nodes) as firstNode, head
MERGE (head)-[:LEADS_TO]->(firstNode)
```

[image]